# Determining the maximum % below average

Tags: probability

Is there a way to determine the maximum percentage of values that fall below the average in a given sample?  How would someone go about this?  How does this relate to what Markov's inequality and Chebyshev's inequality are saying?

Comment: It can be arbitrarily close to $100\%$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a certain factory, there are $999999$ workers, each earning $1$ dollar a day. and $1$ owner, earning $1000000$ dollars a day. Of the people involved with the factory, $99.9999\%$ have earnings that are below average.

Comment: So what happens if we use Chebyshev's inequality on that kind of example?  The information seems far less useful.

Comment: The Chebyshev Inequality is not very relevant. If we bring the "rich" person's income to $\$1.10$, the variance will be very small, but with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you take one sample and make it very large, then all the other samples can be below the average. Thus, if you have $n$ samples, it is possible that the number of samples that are below the average is $n-1$. It is impossible to have all $n$ samples below the average, so the quoted maximum value $n-1$ is tight.